# BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 0000000000000048

Tags: debian, kernel, crash, bugs

I had an issue for some time that my server was crashing without any recognizable reason. Yesterday I finally was able to "catch my server in the act" of crashing and prevented the logs from being wiped upon reboot. I found the following:

```
Sep  1 19:04:30 DebianHomeServer kernel: [11437.330427] BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 0000000000000048
Sep  1 19:04:30 DebianHomeServer kernel: [11437.330597] IP: [<ffffffffc06bec04>] ext4_file_open+0x24/0x280 [ext4]
Sep  1 19:04:30 DebianHomeServer kernel: [11437.333407] PGD 0 
Sep  1 19:04:30 DebianHomeServer kernel: [11437.333451] 
Sep  1 19:04:30 DebianHomeServer kernel: [11437.333553] Oops: 0002 [#808] SMP
Sep  1 19:04:30 DebianHomeServer kernel: [11437.333615] Modules linked in: ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 xt_multiport iptable_filter edac_mce_amd edac_core snd_hda_codec_realtek kvm snd_hda_codec_hdmi joydev snd_hda_codec_generic evdev snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep irqbypass serio_raw snd_pcm pcspkr snd_timer k10temp snd sg soundcore shpchp wmi sp5100_tco button acpi_cpufreq nvidia_drm(PO) drm_kms_helper drm nvidia_modeset(PO) nvidia(PO) ipmi_msghandler it87 hwmon_vid ip_tables x_tables autofs4 ext4 crc16 jbd2 fscrypto ecb glue_helper lrw gf128mul ablk_helper cryptd aes_x86_64 mbcache raid10 raid1 raid0 multipath linear raid456 async_raid6_recov async_memcpy async_pq async_xor async_tx xor raid6_pq libcrc32c crc32c_generic hid_generic usbhid hid md_mod sd_mod ohci_pci firewire_ohci ata_generic xhci_pci ehci_pci xhci_hcd ohci_hcd
Sep  1 19:04:30 DebianHomeServer kernel: [11437.337130]  ehci_hcd firewire_core crc_itu_t i2c_piix4 pata_atiixp usbcore usb_common r8169 mii ahci libahci pata_jmicron libata scsi_mod floppy
Sep  1 19:04:30 DebianHomeServer kernel: [11437.337824] CPU: 2 PID: 16273 Comm: apache2 Tainted: P      D    O    4.9.0-9-amd64 #1 Debian 4.9.168-1+deb9u5
Sep  1 19:04:30 DebianHomeServer kernel: [11437.337911] Hardware name: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. GA-890XA-UD3/GA-890XA-UD3, BIOS FA 04/13/2010
Sep  1 19:04:30 DebianHomeServer kernel: [11437.337996] task: ffff9debe5b30e40 task.stack: ffffb75800b84000
Sep  1 19:04:30 DebianHomeServer kernel: [11437.338062] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffffc06bec04>]  [<ffffffffc06bec04>] ext4_file_open+0x24/0x280 [ext4]
Sep  1 19:04:30 DebianHomeServer kernel: [11437.338219] RSP: 0018:ffffb75800b87dd0  EFLAGS: 00010206
Sep  1 19:04:30 DebianHomeServer kernel: [11437.338284] RAX: 0000000000000048 RBX: ffff9debea20cbc8 RCX: 000000009b45f3a4
Sep  1 19:04:30 DebianHomeServer kernel: [11437.338352] RDX: 39aa73a454b04281 RSI: 000000009b45f3a4 RDI: 0000000000000000
Sep  1 19:04:30 DebianHomeServer kernel: [11437.338421] RBP: ffffb75800b87e80 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: ffff9debea1b02d8
Sep  1 19:04:30 DebianHomeServer kernel: [11437.338489] R10: ffff9debe630e400 R11: 000000000000000c R12: ffff9debea20cbc8
Sep  1 19:04:30 DebianHomeServer kernel: [11437.338557] R13: ffffb75800b87ed0 R14: ffff9deb8aec9e80 R15: ffff9debc4830300
Sep  1 19:04:30 DebianHomeServer kernel: [11437.338627] FS:  00007fd7bc4f1040(0000) GS:ffff9debefc80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Sep  1 19:04:30 DebianHomeServer kernel: [11437.338710] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Sep  1 19:04:30 DebianHomeServer kernel: [11437.338776] CR2: 0000000000000048 CR3: 000000012353e000 CR4: 00000000000006f0
Sep  1 19:04:30 DebianHomeServer kernel: [11437.338843] Stack:
Sep  1 19:04:30 DebianHomeServer kernel: [11437.338902]  8b2a0dff7c28f1f0 ffff9debeab0f000 00000000024000c0 ffff9debe295d400
Sep  1 19:04:30 DebianHomeServer kernel: [11437.339145]  ffff9debea20cbc8 0002000000000000 0000000000000000 ffff9debc4830300
Sep  1 19:04:30 DebianHomeServer kernel: [11437.339386]  ffff9debe61d5800 0000000000000000 8000000100000000 ffff9deb00000000
Sep  1 19:04:30 DebianHomeServer kernel: [11437.339627] Call Trace:
Sep  1 19:04:30 DebianHomeServer kernel: [11437.339696]  [<ffffffffa6e20b37>] ? iterate_dir+0x177/0x1a0
Sep  1 19:04:30 DebianHomeServer kernel: [11437.339765]  [<ffffffffa6e21028>] ? SyS_getdents+0x98/0x120
Sep  1 19:04:30 DebianHomeServer kernel: [11437.339832]  [<ffffffffa6e20d90>] ? fillonedir+0xe0/0xe0
Sep  1 19:04:30 DebianHomeServer kernel: [11437.339901]  [<ffffffffa6c03b7d>] ? do_syscall_64+0x8d/0x100
Sep  1 19:04:30 DebianHomeServer kernel: [11437.339970]  [<ffffffffa721b80e>] ? entry_SYSCALL_64_after_swapgs+0x58/0xc6
Sep  1 19:04:30 DebianHomeServer kernel: [11437.340038] Code: 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 41 57 41 56 41 55 41 54 55 53 48 89 f5 48 89 fb 48 83 ec 60 4c 8b 6f 28 65 48 8b 04 25 28 00 <00> 00 48 89 44 24 58 31 c0 4d 8b bd 60 04 00 00 41 8b 97 80 00 
Sep  1 19:04:30 DebianHomeServer kernel: [11437.342767] RIP  [<ffffffffc06bec04>] ext4_file_open+0x24/0x280 [ext4]
Sep  1 19:04:30 DebianHomeServer kernel: [11437.342905]  RSP <ffffb75800b87dd0>
Sep  1 19:04:30 DebianHomeServer kernel: [11437.342966] CR2: 0000000000000048
Sep  1 19:04:30 DebianHomeServer kernel: [11437.343094] ---[ end trace 0fc6e2d0e65772fc ]---
```

I am using Debian 9.9 with the kernel version Linux 4.9.0-9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.168-1+deb9u5
The log was much, much longer than the excerpt above but I can't paste all of that detail here as there are almost 80,000 lines. The first full entry is

```
Sep  1 01:09:06 DebianHomeServer kernel: [481098.461181] Fixing recursive fault but reboot is needed!
Sep  1 01:09:06 DebianHomeServer kernel: [481098.461188] BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at           (null)
Sep  1 01:09:06 DebianHomeServer kernel: [481098.461193] IP: [<ffffffffa3b095c4>] blk_flush_plug_list+0x74/0x230
Sep  1 01:09:06 DebianHomeServer kernel: [481098.461201] PGD 0 
Oops: 0002 [#4715] SMP
```

I can provide more detail if required but I really, really would appreciate if I could get some feedback on what the issue could be.

Comment: I'm sorry to disappoint you, but I'm pretty sure you're in the wrong place for kernel debugging. I'd suggest you check the bug reports for your distribution (Debian), and if necessary file a new one).

Comment: @roaima: was afraid you would say that. I was hoping someone came across the same issue and found a solution. Bug report already filed. Thanks anyways.